# Alasql select in arrary of array with uknown index

Tags: alasql

suppose I have this structure data

```
data =[ 
 {
"id":1,
"link":[
        {
        "id":3
        },
        {
        "id":1
        },
        {
        "id":2
        }
        ]
},
{
"id":2,
"link":[
         {
          "id":30
          },
         {
         "id":11
         },
         {
         "id":22
         }
         ]

}
]
```

I want see if my structure have a link with `id=11`

```
"SELECT * FROM ? WHERE link->[1]->id=11"
```

work but because I already know that I must check in index 1. How can I check in all indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SEARCH` function would be good if it was fully implemented

```
alasql('SEARCH / link / WHERE(id=11) .. / .. FROM ?',[data]);
```

But the parrent `..` selector is not implemented yet.

I suggest doing a (not totally elegant) user defined function:

```
alasql.fn.deepSearch = function(id, obj){
    return alasql("SEARCH / link / WHERE(id=?) FROM ?", [id, [obj]]).length
}

alasql('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE deepSearch(11,_)',[data]);
```

Comment: I replaced `[id, [obj])` with `[id, [obj]])` + included version 0.2.6 instad of version 0.1.9 in your code and it now spits out `[{"id":2,"link":[{"id":30},{"id":11},{"id":22}]}]` - http://jsfiddle.net/8g4k1hjo/3/

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is

```
alasql('SEARCH / AS @a link / WHERE(id=11) @a FROM ?',[data]);
```

Here `AS @a` saves current element into the variable `@a`, and the second `@a` retrieves it.